# jQuery animate confusing behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm admittedly new to jQuery, but I know a bit of javascript, I'm trying to animate a div with a couple of animations.

I want the div to first move to the center of the page
Then I want it to flip after it has reached the center and then expand.

The trouble I'm having is using the `.animate()` method to change the `top` and `left` properties of the div to get it to the center.

---

The issue is that the .animate method in the moveToCenter function doesn't actually animate the movement to the center, It just skips the animation part (properties change, but the change is not animated) and proceeds to the flip and rest of it.

Can some-one tell me why this is happening/Where I am going wrong?

And how can it(if at all) be fixed?

---

**The HTML**

```
<div id="flip" style="background-color:#ff0000;
               width:200px;
               height:200px;
               position:absolute">

  <h4> printf("Hello World"); </h4>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
function moveToCenter()
{
    $('#flip').animate({'top':'300','left':'300'});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flip').click( function() {

            moveToCenter(); //function that is supposed to moves the div to the center

            $(this).flip({
                    content: 'Scanf()',
                    color: '#00FF00',
                    direction: 'lr',
                    onEnd:  function(){ $('#flip').animate({ 
                    'height' : '400', 'width': '300'
                    }       
                    ,'500','swing');

                    lol(); //Another function that does some other animations
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip after the animation is done, add a callback like this:

```
function moveToCenter(done){
    $('#flip').animate({'top':'300','left':'300'}, done);
}
```

The function will call the `done` method when the animation is complete. So now you just need to pass it:

```
moveToCenter(function() {
    // now the animation is done, move on
    $(this).flip({ //... etc
```

Comment: Why is adding the callback necessary ?

I mean even if the function executes asynchronously, it's should move and flip at the *same* time. Not just skip the animation.
What is going on?

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to flip *after* the animation, quoting: "I want the div to first move to the center of the page Then I want it to flip"

Comment: Yes ,that is correct. What I am asking was in relation to why it won't work without a callback.
The problem was that even a different assumption, the output didn't make sense.
So what I was trying to say was, if the functions do not execute in order(which is what I assumed originally, while writing the code), i.e do not wait for the previous function to finish exectution, then it means the two functions should run simultaneously, that means simultaneous movement and flipping, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Comment: @ayos It would be a bit naive to think that a plugin will play nicely with an ongoing animation. You can ask "why", but since you don’t want that anyway, I suggest you start thinking about your animation sequence in callbacks.

Comment: You're right, but I'm still having trouble deciding where to use callbacks and where simple queuing will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function flipElem() {
    $('#flip').flip({
        content: 'Scanf()',
        color: '#00FF00',
        direction: 'lr',
        onEnd: function() {
            $('#flip').animate({
                'height': '400',
                'width': '300'
            }, '500', 'swing');

        }
    });
}

function moveToCenter(elem) {
    $(elem).animate({
        'top': '300',
        'left': '300'
    }, flipElem);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flip').click(function() {
        moveToCenter(this);
    });
});​
```

Registering a callback as soon as the move to center animation is complete. If you do if before it completes, it could have weird effects, but nevertheless, quite possible.

Little optimization : passing an element to flipElem instead of using $('#flip') again, similar to moveToCenter(this)

Comment: Seems @David beat me to it ;-)